# preview not matching with iOS device

Tags: ios, xcode

my preview for my device looks like this:

[image]

but when i run it on my device it looks like this:

[image]

could be something to do with the size of my image?  maybe it's something to do with setting the specific image in code?  the table view is inside a container view in my main view.

Comment: You can try using auto-layout, [this is a tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1?utm_source=tuicool)

Comment: How did you set up auto layout? Did you enable the simulator device in preview?

Comment: i added constraints, but shouldn't the "preview" of what the device will look match what it looks like on my device?

Comment: i have constraints constant width and height, top of cell, and horizontally aligned in the center

Comment: It is ill-conceived to think of the storyboard as a "preview" anything you do here can easily be overridden in code anyway. Things to look for: any warnings regarding the constraints in the storyboard, is the image hooked up to the UITableViewCell.imageView (this is positioned to the left).

Comment: ya the image was hooked up to the cell.imageView instead of my IBOutlet image view, thanks T. Benjamin Larson

Comment: The preview in Xcode can be accessed using assistant editor. The storyboard itself is not a preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting image inside `tableview cell's default imageview`. Insted of doing this set image inside `prototype cell's imageview` which you have taken.

```
cell.imageoutletname.image=image;
```

Answer (score 0):

i was not setting the image correctly in code.

i had: `cell.imageView?.image = image`

instead of `cell.icon.image = image` "icon" being the name for the image view IBOutlet outlet i had for the cell.